# Update Table by Matching Invoice ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have what is probably a simple problem.  My table is a collection of invoices over the month.  My ship_to_state column in my table is only showing the actual ship to state on one row on each invoice. I need to update my table so that the ship to state value appears for every GL Account line item on that invoice.  Right now, it is only showing up for my 12000-99 GL Account.

Here is my current query:

```
UPDATE INVOICES
SET SHIP_TO_STATE = 
(SELECT SHIP_TO_STATE FROM INVOICES WHERE GL_ACCOUNT_ID = '12000-99' 
AND INVOICES.INVOICE_ID = INVOICES.INVOICE_ID);
```

Here is my table:

```
CUSTOMER_ID INVOICE_ID  ITEM_ID GL_ACCOUNT_ID   SHIP_TO_STATE
Customer1   38441        ADM       46000-99 
Customer1   38441        ADM       12000-99         GA
Customer2   42809        GSD307    40100-02 
Customer2   42809        GSD310    40100-01 
Customer2   42809        GSW311    40100-01 
Customer2   42809        GSD200    40100-01 
Customer2   42809        FSR270    40100-02 
Customer2   42809        ADM       12000-99         WA
Customer3   42810        GSS10-100 40100-01 
Customer3   42810        GSS10-500 40100-05 
Customer3   42810        GSD210    40100-01 
Customer3   42810        ADM       45100-99 
Customer3   42810        ADM       12000-99         AL
Customer4   42811        PSG550-L  40100-02 
Customer4   42811        PSG550-M  40100-02 
Customer4   42811        ADM       12000-99         GA
Customer5   42812        GSS10-100 40100-01 
Customer5   42812        GSS10-350 40100-05 
Customer5   42812        GSD200    40100-01 
Customer5   42812        ADM       12000-99         NC
Customer6   42813        FSF105    40100-02 
Customer6   42813        FSF135    40100-02 
Customer6   42813        GSD310    40100-01 
Customer6   42813        GSW311    40100-01 
Customer6   42813        GSD190    40100-01 
Customer6   42813        GSW312    40100-01 
Customer6   42813        ADM       45100-99 
Customer6   42813        ADM       12000-99        TX
```

I am looking forward to your feedback.  Thanks.

Comment: I agree with Gordon's observation in his answer: You should have a separate, smaller table where you keep information that refers strictly to an invoice (such as the `ship_to_state` information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE INVOICES
SET SHIP_TO_STATE = 
(SELECT MAX(SHIP_TO_STATE) FROM INVOICES i WHERE i.INVOICE_ID = INVOICES.INVOICE_ID);
```

This returns only one record per invoice id and fixes the aliasing issue mentioned elsewhere. If there is no ship_to_state value, it will update with NULL. If there is more than one, it will pick the later one alphabetically - there are ways around that if it's an issue.

Comment: Actually, if there is more than one, then the requirement doesn't quite make sense to begin with.

Comment: True! So that shouldn't be a problem then.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a correlated subquery.  You need a table alias or two:

```
UPDATE INVOICES
    SET SHIP_TO_STATE = (SELECT i.SHIP_TO_STATE
                         FROM INVOICES i
                         WHERE i.GL_ACCOUNT_ID = '12000-99' AND
                               i.INVOICE_ID = INVOICES.INVOICE_ID
                        );
```

Shouldn't you be storing this information in a table that has one row per invoice_id?  It is strange that such an id would be repeated in a table called `INVOICES`.

Comment: This won't work any better than the OP's query. The `INVOICE_ID` is not unique in the `INVOICES` table, so the scalar subquery will throw an error for returning too many rows.

Comment: @mathguy: in contrast to the query in the question this will actually work because the condition `INVOICES.INVOICE_ID = INVOICES.INVOICE_ID` in the question is not doing what jk4 things it's doing

Comment: @mathguy . . . The invoice id AND `gl_account_id` appear to be unique.  You should do a better job of looking at the question before you comment and downvote.

Comment: Err - no, actually - sorry - what I didn't read closely was your answer, not the question. I didn't see that you were still only updating the base table for a single `invoice_id`. The OP wanted to update the entire table, not just a few rows (for a single `invoice_id`). You are right, I should read more closely - in this case, the answer, not the question; and indeed, that alone (not answering the OP's requirement) wasn't deserving of a downvote. Unfortunately I can't undo it; I'll refrain from a downvote sometime in the future.

Comment: And - just so you know and you don't think I only downvote your posts (I am not saying you believe that - I will only say it "just in case"); I also upvote many of your answers. Sometimes you can see that, because I leave comments, sometimes you don't. I try to be fair, and in cases - like this - when I fail, I appreciate the feedback (even if the feedback is that I was wrong).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - see above; I did, indeed, misread Gordon's answer, I didn't realize he was still updating rows only for one `id`, and not across the entire table as the OP's requirement was.

Comment: Looking more closely, the combination of those two columns is **not** unique in the data. `42809` and `40100-01` appears in triplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `MERGE` statement (the syntax is a bit clearer than updating through a join or through correlated subqueries). The solution below assumes that in the current table you have no more than one **non-null** value for each `invoice_id`.

Syntax may a bit off (you didn't provide data for testing*).  **By which I mean, no CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements*.

```
merge into invoices i
  using ( select invoice_id, ship_to_state 
          from   invoices 
          where  ship_to_state is not null )  s
    on (i.invoice_id = s.invoice_id)
when matched then update
  set i.ship_to_state = s.ship_to_state
    where i.ship_to_state is null
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICES ( CUSTOMER_ID, INVOICE_ID, ITEM_ID, GL_ACCOUNT_ID, SHIP_TO_STATE ) AS
SELECT 'Customer1', 38441, 'ADM',       '46000-99', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer1', 38441, 'ADM',       '12000-99', 'GA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer2', 42809, 'GSD307',    '40100-02', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer2', 42809, 'GSD310',    '40100-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer2', 42809, 'GSW311',    '40100-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer2', 42809, 'GSD200',    '40100-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer2', 42809, 'FSR270',    '40100-02', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer2', 42809, 'ADM',       '12000-99', 'WA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer3', 42810, 'GSS10-100', '40100-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer3', 42810, 'GSS10-500', '40100-05', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer3', 42810, 'GSD210',    '40100-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer3', 42810, 'ADM',       '45100-99', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer3', 42810, 'ADM',       '12000-99', 'AL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer4', 42811, 'PSG550-L',  '40100-02', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer4', 42811, 'PSG550-M',  '40100-02', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer4', 42811, 'ADM',       '12000-99', 'GA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer5', 42812, 'GSS10-100', '40100-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer5', 42812, 'GSS10-350', '40100-05', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer5', 42812, 'GSD200',    '40100-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer5', 42812, 'ADM',       '12000-99', 'NC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer6', 42813, 'FSF105',    '40100-02', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer6', 42813, 'FSF135',    '40100-02', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer6', 42813, 'GSD310',    '40100-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer6', 42813, 'GSW311',    '40100-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer6', 42813, 'GSD190',    '40100-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer6', 42813, 'GSW312',    '40100-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer6', 42813, 'ADM',       '45100-99', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customer6', 42813, 'ADM',       '12000-99', 'TX' FROM DUAL;
```

**Update**:

```
MERGE INTO invoices dst
USING ( SELECT MAX( SHIP_TO_STATE ) OVER ( PARTITION BY invoice_id )
                 AS new_ship_to_state
        FROM   invoices ) src
ON ( src.ROWID = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET ship_to_state = src.new_ship_to_state;
```

**Result**:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices;

CUSTOMER_ INVOICE_ID ITEM_ID   GL_ACCOU SH
--------- ---------- --------- -------- --
Customer1      38441 ADM       46000-99 GA
Customer1      38441 ADM       12000-99 GA
Customer2      42809 GSD307    40100-02 WA
Customer2      42809 GSD310    40100-01 WA
Customer2      42809 GSW311    40100-01 WA
Customer2      42809 GSD200    40100-01 WA
Customer2      42809 FSR270    40100-02 WA
Customer2      42809 ADM       12000-99 WA
Customer3      42810 GSS10-100 40100-01 AL
Customer3      42810 GSS10-500 40100-05 AL
Customer3      42810 GSD210    40100-01 AL
Customer3      42810 ADM       45100-99 AL
Customer3      42810 ADM       12000-99 AL
Customer4      42811 PSG550-L  40100-02 GA
Customer4      42811 PSG550-M  40100-02 GA
Customer4      42811 ADM       12000-99 GA
Customer5      42812 GSS10-100 40100-01 NC
Customer5      42812 GSS10-350 40100-05 NC
Customer5      42812 GSD200    40100-01 NC
Customer5      42812 ADM       12000-99 NC
Customer6      42813 FSF105    40100-02 TX
Customer6      42813 FSF135    40100-02 TX
Customer6      42813 GSD310    40100-01 TX
Customer6      42813 GSW311    40100-01 TX
Customer6      42813 GSD190    40100-01 TX
Customer6      42813 GSW312    40100-01 TX
Customer6      42813 ADM       45100-99 TX
Customer6      42813 ADM       12000-99 TX
```